# How to merge two `value_counts` results without data loss?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to accumulate value counts, but the simple addition does not do the trick.

Suppose I have many many [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), e.g., :

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,2,None], dtype=object)
b = pd.Series([3,2,2,None], dtype=object)
...
```

and I want to produce

```
pd.concat([a,b,...]).value_counts(dropna=False)
2       4
None    2
1       1
3       1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

*incrementally*, i.e., from

```
vc_a = a.value_counts(dropna=False)
vc_b = b.value_counts(dropna=False)
...
```

Alas, the simple `vc_a + vc_b` produces

```
1       NaN
2       4.0
3       NaN
None    2.0
```

i.e., the objects that are present in only one of the series are not counted correctly.

So, how do I merge a bunch of counting series?

Comment: `vc_a.add(vs_b, fill_value=0)`?

Comment: If you have many Series: `pd.concat([vc_a, vc_b, vc_c], axis=1).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

### [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
coco = collections.Counter()
for vc in vc_iterator():
    coco += vc.to_dict()
vc_sum = pd.Series(coco)
```

### @BigBen: [`pandas.Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)

```
vc_sum = pd.Series()
for vc in vc_iterator():
    vc_sum = vc_sum.add(vc, fill_value=0)
```

### @mozway: [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
vc_sum = pd.concat(vc_list, axis="columns").sum(axis="columns")
```